# Script to migrate data from one source to another

Tags: bash, perl, sed, scripting

I have a .h file, among other things, containing data in this format

```
struct X[]{
{"Field", "value1 value2 value"},
{"Field2", "value11 value12 value232"},
{"Field3", "x  y z"},
{"Field4", "a bbb s"},
{"Field5", "sfsd sdfdsf sdfs"};
/****************/
};
```

I have text file containing, values that I want to replace in .h file with new values

```
value1   Valuesdfdsf1  
value2   Value1dfsdf  
value3   Value1_another  
sfsd     sfsd_ewew   
sdfdsf   sdfdsf_ew 
sdfs     sfsd_new
```

And the resulting .h file will contain the replacements from the text file above. Everything else remains the same.

```
struct X[]{
    {"Field1", "value11 value12 value232"},
    {"Field2", "value11 value12 value232"},
    {"Field3", "x  y z"},
    {"Field4", "a bbb s"},
    {"Field5", "sfsd_ewew sdfdsf_ew sdfs_new"};
    /****************/
    };
```

Please help me come with a solution to accomplish it using unix tools: awk, perl, bash, sed, etc

Comment: Are field-value pairs always on the same line and values separated by single space?

Comment: space/tab, at least one space is for sure

Comment: Shouldn't value2 from first line be replaced with Value1dfsdf  
?

Comment: You're right  -- it should have been. Fixed.

Comment: Your value[123] don't seem to be replaced correctly in your desired result example.

Comment: How big is your replacement key file?

Comment: @Dennis Williamson  it's about 5000 keys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This script should work
***keyval*** is the file containing key value pairs
***filetoreplace*** is the file containing data to be modified
The file named ***changed*** will contain the changes

```
#!/bin/sh
echo  

keylist=`cat keyval | awk '{ print $1}'`  


while read line   
do   

for i in $keylist  
do  


if echo $line | grep -wq $i; then  

    value=`grep -w $i keyval | awk '{print $2}'`  
    line=`echo $line | sed -e "s/$i/$value/g"`  
fi  

done  

echo $line >> changed  

done < filetoreplace
```

Answer (score 3):

```
cat junk/n2.txt | perl -e '{use File::Slurp; my @r = File::Slurp::read_file("junk/n.txt"); my %r = map {chomp; (split(/\s+/,$_))[0,1]} @r; while (<>) { unless (/^\s*{"/) {print $_; next;}; my ($pre,$values,$post) = ($_ =~ /^(\s*{"[^"]+", ")([^"]+)(".*)$/); my @new_values = map { exists $r{$_} ? $r{$_}:$_ } split(/\s+/,$values); print $pre . join(" ",@new_values) . $post . "\n"; }}'
```

Result:

```
struct X[]{
{"Field", "value1 Value1dfsdf value"},
{"Field2", "value11 value12 value232"},
{"Field3", "x y z"},
{"Field4", "a bbb s"},
{"Field5", "sfsd_ewew sdfdsf_ew sfsd_new"};
/****************/
};
```

Code untangled:

```
use File::Slurp;
my @replacements = File::Slurp::read_file("junk/n.txt"); 
my %r = map {chomp; (split(/\s+/,$_))[0,1]} @replacements; 
while (<>) {
    unless (/^\s*{"/) {print $_; next;}
    my ($pre,$values,$post) = ($_ =~ /^(\s*{"[^"]+", ")([^"]+)(".*)$/); 
    my @new_values = map { exists $r{$_} ? $r{$_} : $_ } split(/\s+/, $values);
    print $pre . join(" ",@new_values) . $post . "\n";
}
```

Comment: God I hate how Perl looks. Power by ugliness! Next on my learning list though :)

Comment: @Morlock - That's not how **Perl** looks. That's how a Perl **one-liner** looks - designed to take as little space on the string as possible. Written in proper Perl coding style, a vast majority of the punctuation marks in the above code go away and leave actually readable program. The only pieces that still look like they are encoded are regular expressions which look 100% the same in any language.

Comment: I can but dude, it's short day before Thanksgiving :) Ask for break as a separate question later on and someone on Perl tag or myself would be glad to assist. Just not now :)

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

# you need to populate %lookup from the text file
my %lookup = qw(
    value1   Valuesdfdsf1
    value2   Value1dfsdf
    value3   Value1_another
    sfsd     sfsd_ewew
    sdfdsf   sdfdsf_ew
    sdfs     sfsd_new
);

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    if ( $line =~ /^struct \w+\Q[]/ ) {
        print $line;
        process_struct(\*DATA, \%lookup);
    }
    else {
        print $line;
    }
}

sub process_struct {
    my ($fh, $lookup) = @_;

    while (my $line = <$fh> ) {
        unless ( $line =~ /^{"(\w+)", "([^"]+)"}([,;])\s+/ ) {
            print $line;
            return;
        }
        my ($f, $v, $p) = ($1, $2, $3);
        $v =~ s/(\w+)/exists $lookup->{$1} ? $lookup->{$1} : $1/eg;
        printf qq|{"%s", "%s"}%s\n|, $f, $v, $p;
    }
    return;
}

__DATA__
struct X[]{
{"Field", "value1 value2 value"},
{"Field2", "value11 value12 value232"},
{"Field3", "x  y z"},
{"Field4", "a bbb s"},
{"Field5", "sfsd sdfdsf sdfs"};
/****************/
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple looking program:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use File::Copy;

use constant {
    OLD_HEADER_FILE   => "headerfile.h",
    NEW_HEADER_FILE   => "newheaderfile.h",
    DATA_TEXT_FILE    => "data.txt",
};

open (HEADER, "<", OLD_HEADER_FILE) or
die qq(Can't open file old header file ") . OLD_HEADER_FILE . qq(" for reading);

open (NEWHEADER, ">", NEW_HEADER_FILE) or
die qq(Can't open file new header file ") . NEW_HEADER_FILE . qq(" for writing);

open (DATA, "<", DATA_TEXT_FILE) or
die qq(Can't open file data file ") . DATA_TEXT_FILE . qq(" for reading); 

#
# Put Replacement Data in a Hash
#

my %dataHash;
while (my $line = <DATA>) {
    chomp($line);
    my ($key, $value) = split (/\s+/, $line);
    $dataHash{$key} = $value if ($key and $value);
}
close (DATA);

#
# NOW PARSE THOUGH HEADER
# 

while (my $line = <HEADER>) {
    chomp($line);
    if ($line =~ /^\s*\{"Field/) {
        foreach my $key (keys(%dataHash)) {
            $line =~ s/\b$key\b/$dataHash{$key}/g;
        }
    }
    print NEWHEADER "$line\n";
}

close (HEADER);
close (NEWHEADER);
copy(NEW_HEADER_FILE, OLD_HEADER_FILE) or
  die qq(Unable to replace ") . OLD_HEADER_FILE . qq(" with ") . NEW_HEADER_FILE . qq(");
```

I could make it more *efficient* by using `map`, but that makes it harder to understand.

Basically:

- I open three files, the original Header, the new Header I'm building, and the data file
- I first put my data into a hash where the replacement text is keyed by the original text. (Could have done it the other way around if I wanted.
- I then go through each line of the original header.
  **  If I see a line that looks like its a field line, I know that I might have to do a replacement.
  **  For each entry in my `%dataHash`, I do a substitution of the `$key` with the `$dataHash{$key}` replacement value. I use the `\b` to mark *word boundries*. This way, `field11` is not substituted because I see `field1` in that string.
  ** Now I write the line back to my new header file. If I didn't replace anything, I just write back the original line.
- Once I finish, I copy the new header over the old header file.

Comment: Thanks for the alternative easier-on-the-eye version :)

Answer (score 0):

This might be kind of slow if your files are big.

```
gawk -F '[ \t]*|"' 'FNR == NR {repl[$1]=$2;next}{for (f=1;f<=NF;++f) for (r in repl) if ($f == r) $f=repl[r]; print} ' keyfile file.h
```